# help on database in c#

Tags: c#

I have an Sql database in my C# program since c# allows you to build database inside the program. The question can an attribute(column) in a database be a range. for example, can I have attribute for the weight such as one of its values 120-130, so that it's more easy than  specifying 10 values.

Comment: What do You mean database inside program?

Answer (score 1):

You could use two columns: Min and Max.

```
 Name   | Min | Max
--------------------
 Item 1 | 120 | 130
          ...
```

Comment: Phil is right. Better have min max as ints or long ints. You could then find a value in a range: Random r = new Random(); int n = r.Next(obj.Min, obj.Max);

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the Server Explorer in Visual Studio.  If you are talking about a SQL Server database that is being used by your application this can be done using the a constraints.

If you add two, one that checks that Weight > 129 and one that checks that Weight < 131, it should prevent people from entering values outside of those ranges.

That said I would probably enforce this business rule through your C# Application logic rather than in the Database structure.

In other words present people with a drop down list to select from that contains only the range of values that you want.  You could do server side validation on the selected values if security is a concern.